# python flask mod_wsgi application crashing on apache with high memory usage

Tags: python, apache, memory, mod-wsgi

I have an apache webserver which I have setup a website using python based flask using mod_wsgi.

I'm having a problem with my application crashing. The python script reads in a lot of data, and on this particular machine, needs to swap (only has 4GB RAM) a bit in order to process the data it reads in before it can get to a point where the data is optimized and the code will use less memory (during this processing, memory usage peaks at about 7GB, but I have an 8GB swap file and 4GB RAM), which takes several minutes upon first load. The application crashes when run through apache and I am not getting much information as far as debugging what apache is doing and why. Here is all that is coming up in error.log

```
[Thu Feb 06 06:58:33 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29315): Starting process 'website' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=1.
[Thu Feb 06 06:58:33 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29315): Initializing Python.
[Thu Feb 06 07:15:40 2014] [error] [client MASKED] Premature end of script headers: website.wsgi, referer: http://MASKED/
[Thu Feb 06 07:15:40 2014] [info] mod_wsgi (pid=29315): Process 'website' has died, restarting.
```

I am able to test the application using flask's built in development webserver, and after the code gets done processing the data, it is able to clear up some memory, and have plenty of free RAM to run (about 2.3GB free RAM after the initial processing is done).

I can get the application to run using apache if a much smaller test dataset is used.

I think there may be some timeout or memory limitation in apache that is not configured, but I am not sure what this could be. I have tried setting

```
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 3001
```

in apache2.conf file, but this doesn't seem to help.

I have also set processes=1 threads=1 under WSGIDaemonProcess in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file just to reduce the amount of memory that is used.

Comment: Provide the rest of the mod_wsgi configuration. You could well not be using daemon mode and so running in embedded mode, meaning you may be doing the memory exhaustive work in multiple processes. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode

Comment: Also Timeout directive is totally unrelated and is to do with when blocked operations on socket connections timeout. Not sure what you think it is for.

Comment: Are you talking about in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file or /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just can't see how Timeout is at all relevant. You still haven't provided the rest of the mod_wsgi configuration as asked.